get the resources path in Spring
I am working on a project where I need to download the build's resources folder. I want to declare the path of the resources folder as a configuration property and later access that in my service. How do I fetch and add the correct resources folder path in the configuration ?
I tried using this directly but looks like a wrong approach -
String resourcesPath =  getClass().getResource("/../../resources/").getPath();
I want to add this as a configuration property. How can I do that?

Normally the resources folder contents get packaged up inside the application's jar (or war) file.
When you say path are you meaning a file system location because there won't be one, not unless the runtime execution of your application extracts the jar contents into the runtime file system (this is not normal).
One approach, if you know the paths of all the resources you want, you can access this from the Classpath Resource folder, so you can pull the assets out in a binary stream and re-construct concrete files.
Another approach would be to obtain a file handle of the application's .jar file at runtime and then programmatically explore the jar file contents (or unzip it).  But it is common that the packaged application will place within the same path structure both compiled .class files and anything that was in your resources folder, meaning isolating "the build's resources" will be difficult.  This approach will be easier if all the resources you want are a distinct path and not just "loose" in the root.
Overall, I think you need to approach the problem in a different way; find a build plug-in that package up the resources into a zip, etc in additional to the normal packaging of the resources folder, and ALSO arrange for that zip file to packaged inside the app.  Unfortunately, I don't know of such a plug-in...

Thanks for the reply. I will try to tackle this in a different way!
